# "Weakened Sophie Germain" primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a name for a prime $p$ such that $2p+1$ has no prime factors less than a given positive integer $k$? Is there an infinite number of such primes for every positive integer $k$?

This question arose while trying to fix this [previously erroneous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/366730/195155), recently corrected  by the poster after prompting by me when this answer helped me understand what might possibly have gone wrong. I think it is still useful as justification for the scarcely documented argument there, and I am considering either adding a comment there or editing that answer to add this as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to arrange using [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). For $p_2, p_3, \dots $ an enumeration of the odd primes consider the system of congruences

$$2p + 1 \equiv 2 \bmod p_i, 2 \le i \le k$$

which has a solution $\bmod p_2 \dots p_k$ by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). This gives an arithmetic progression (with no common factors) such that any prime in that arithmetic progression has the property that $2p + 1$ is not divisible by $2, p_2, \dots p_k$, and by Dirichlet's theorem there are infinitely many such primes.

Comment: This is pretty close to the only sort of thing we can do. If you can't relate some condition on primes to being in an arithmetic progression it's probably completely hopeless to prove that infinitely many primes satisfy it, with rare exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, it was very helpful. I apologize that the question, it seems, is judged to not be of high enough quality.

Comment: I don't really understand why the question was closed. Seems like a fine question to me, although I guess more context would have been helpful.